# sort while inserting or copy and sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, insert

I have an iterator that gives me n elements. Currently I copy them one by one into an ArrayList and then call Collections.Sort() on that list to obtain a sorted ArrayList. This takes nlog(n)+n operations. Is there a faster way to do it, i.e. can I already use the insertion operation to a certain degree?

The iterator does not give any sorting, the elements occur pretty much randomly.

Comment: Are your elements are unique?

Comment: Try radix sort, it's `o(n+k)`.

Comment: If your list is supposed to be an ordered list why *not* handle it at insertion?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils See my comment to Kent's answer below. Inserting into an ArrayList, while keeping all other elements in the array in order and in the Array has a runtime of O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have only that iterator, I don't see faster solutions.  note that `nlogn+n` is also `O(nlogn)`.

if you want to "sort while inserting", you need do binary search on each insertion, it would be  `O(nlogn)` too. I don't think it would be much faster than what you have.

TreeSet can save you from the binary search implementation, but basically it is the same logic.

Comment: @Kent thanks for your answer. I am trying not to think of this problem in Landau notation, since the smaller the constant factors in front of the nlog(n), the better in my application.
Therefore performing insertion sort with binary search at a first glace looks very promising, but since I am working on an ArrayList, for each inserted element, I might have to shift some O(n) elements which will make it just as fast/slow as my original approach. So I will stick to that for now.
Thanks again for thinking it through with me.

Answer (score 1):

Since an iterator is not a collection nor container, it is not possible to sort directly in the iterator, like you already noticed. The method that you are using seems to be the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If your elements are unique you could drop them into a TreeSet and then copy them out of the TreeSet into an ArrayList. That may not actually be any faster than what you are already doing though.

Beyond that you are unlikely to be able to optimise further than you already have. Writing your own insertion sort would almost certainly be slower than just using the highly optimised Java sort routines.

You could consider looking at the new Java Streams API in Java 8 though. That would allow you to do this by opening the iterator as a stream, sorting it, then collating it to your final collection.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object rather than raw data type (such as int , double) in your array, the cost of the object copy must be considered. In this situation, sort the array index may be a better way. Use search data structure map/set is better only when you need to process sorting and inserting simultaneously.